# Como comparar valor do Map e Json em flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, dart, map

Preciso pesquisar dentro desse `Json` o que eu digitar no `TextField`

O controller:

```dart
TextEditingController searchController = TextEditingController();
String variavel_json = '{"nome":"Marcelo", "email":"marcelo@vpeventos.com"}';
```

A função de pesquisa:

```dart
void printJson() {
  setState(() { 
    Map json = jsonDecode(variavel_json);
    if(json["nome"] == searchController){
      print(json["nome"]);
    }else{
      print("Nenhum nome encontrado");
    }
  });
}
```

O `TextField`:

```dart
TextField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: searchText,
    labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
  ),
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  controller: searchController,
),
```

E o botão que chama o `controller`:

```dart
ButtonTheme(
  height: 30.0,
  child: RaisedButton(
    onPressed: printJson,
    shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
    child: Text(
      "Printar JSON",
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 30),
    ), //Text
    color: Colors.blue,
  ), //RaisedButton
),
```

O retorno que eu tenho no console é sempre o `else`. Gostaria de entender como eu poderia fazer essa pesquisa dentro do Map. Sou novo na linguagem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buscando complementar a resposta do @JulioHenrique, trouxe algumas melhorias para o seu desenvolvimento. 
Como você pode vir a ter outros dados nesse `JSON` informado, seria uma boa você colocar os dados em classes estruturadas e trabalhar em cima disso.

Abaixo segue um exemplo que pode ser testado no [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/)

Crie a classe que receberá os dados de cada objeto do teu `JSON`

```
class Conta {
    String nome;
    String email;

    Conta({
      this.nome,
      this.email
    });

    factory Conta.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Conta(
        nome: json["nome"],
        email: json["email"]
    );
}
```

Para poder filtrar o texto digitado pelo usuário, transforme o seu `JSON` em uma Lista que receberá objetos do tipo `Conta`

```
  String json = '[{"nome":"Marcelo", "email":"marcelo@vpeventos.com"}, {"nome":"Caio", "email":"caio@doido.com"}, {"nome":"Caio", "email":"caioloco@eventos.com"}]';
  final jsonMap = jsonDecode(json);

  List<Conta> contas;

  contas = (jsonMap as List).map((item) => Conta.fromJson(item)).toList();
```

Com isso você terá uma lista com todas as contas existentes em seu `JSON`, para realizar a pesquisa basta apenas criar o método de busca

```
  void buscarConta({String nome}){
    List<Conta> contasFiltradas = contas.where((item) => item.nome.toLowerCase()==nome.toLowerCase()).toList();

    for (var x=0; x<contasFiltradas.length; x++){
      print("Registro encontrado");
      print('  Nome filtrado: '+ contasFiltradas[x].nome +'\n  Email Filtrado:'+ contasFiltradas[x].email);
    }
  }
```

Para utilizar o método criado faça da seguinte forma

```
bucarConta(searchController.text);
```

> O resultado está sendo apenas printado na tela, mas você pode
>   modificar o método para que ele retorne um objeto ou mais.

Segue o código completo:

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  String json = '[{"nome":"Marcelo", "email":"marcelo@vpeventos.com"}, {"nome":"Caio", "email":"caio@doido.com"}, {"nome":"Caio", "email":"caioloco@eventos.com"}]';
  final jsonMap = jsonDecode(json);

  List<Conta> contas;

  contas = (jsonMap as List).map((item) => Conta.fromJson(item)).toList();

  void buscarConta({String nome}){
    List<Conta> contasFiltradas = contas.where((item) => item.nome.toLowerCase()==nome.toLowerCase()).toList();

    for (var x=0; x<contasFiltradas.length; x++){
      print("Registro encontrado");
      print('  Nome filtrado: '+ contasFiltradas[x].nome +'\n  Email Filtrado:'+ contasFiltradas[x].email);
    }
  }

  buscarConta(nome: searchController.Text);
}

class Conta {
    String nome;
    String email;

    Conta({
      this.nome,
      this.email
    });

    factory Conta.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Conta(
        nome: json["nome"],
        email: json["email"]
    );
}
```

Comment: Sensacional cara, Muito obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Creio que o problema esteja aqui:

```dart
if(json["nome"] == searchController){
  print(json["nome"]);
}
```

Você está comparando um objeto `String` (value do map) com um objeto do tipo `TextEditingController`, que nunca serão iguais, por isso sempre cai no `else`.

Você precisa pegar o valor através da propriedade `text`.

```dart
if(json["nome"] == searchController.text){
  print(json["nome"]);
}
```

Um exemplo prático e rápido comparando um valor do map:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

main() {
  final json = '{"nome":"Marcelo", "email":"marcelo@vpeventos.com"}';
  print('Json: $json');

  final map = jsonDecode(json);
  print('Map: $map');

  final nomeUm = 'Marcelo';
  if(map['nome'] == nomeUm) {
    print('Nome igual');
  }
}
```

Comment: Entendo, mas no caso ai você está atribuindo o nomeUm ao Marcelo então o comparativo sempre vai dar certo. Como eu pegaria o texto que o usuario digitar para fazer a comparação ?

Comment: Sempre vai dar certo porque é um exemplo, se você ver ali na resposta, um pouco acima, tem como você deve fazer `if(json["nome"] == searchController.text){`. Usando o text do searchController.

Comment: Ah sim, mas mesmo com essa propriedade `text` a pesquisa ainda cai no `else`

Comment: Qual o valor que está imprimindo no `text`? Debuga e inspecional essa variável

Comment: Como eu poderia fazer esse debug ? tem alguma ferramenta ou algo parecido com php com uma especie de `var_dump($variavel)` ?

Comment: Pode utilizar as funções `debugPrint` ou `print` para simplesmente imprimir os valores. Ou utilizar a sua IDE para rodar em modo debug e conseguir inspecionar as variáveis. Mais informações: https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/debugging

Comment: Consegui achar o erro aqui. Depois de printar o que vinha na `searchController` percebi um erro que tinha na sintaxe do Json. Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Só mais uma duvida, quando eu adiciono mais um usuario com nome e-mail sempre pega o ultimo. Alguma ideia do que pode ser isso ?

Comment: @MarceloL nesse caso você está arquitetando seu problema de forma errada, um Map nunca irá permitir uma `key` duplicada. Só seria possível com Maps diferentes ou com uma lista de valores para a key.