# Popular Dropdown com api

Tags: json, flutter, dart

Olá,
Estou tentando recuperar os dados json de de uma URL, estou seguindo este tutorial

https://inducesmile.com/google-flutter/how-to-populate-dropdownbutton-using-json-api-in-flutter/
Consegui reproduzir com sucesso.

Mas com a minha url Json estou com problemas.
O Json é um pouco diferente;

Formato do Json do Tutorial

```
[{"id": 1, "name": "Leanne Graham"},{"id": 2,"name": "Ervin Howell"}]
```

Formato Json minha URL

```
{"data":[{ "id":1, "name":"Acre" }, { "id":2, "name":"Alagoas" }]}
```

Esta é a parte que estou com problemas

```
final items = json.decode(response.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
```

Como seguinte erro:

```
NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' has no instance method 'cast' with matching arguments.
```

Comment: Não precisa fazer um cast, o retorno de json.decode() já é um Map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu respondi uma pergunta parecida a alguns dias atrás, você pode se basear nela para corrigir o seu problema, realizando uma pequena alteração...

Essa é minha resposta de uma outra pergunta [Como comparar valor do Map e Json em flutter?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/421475/87785)

**Vamos ver como ficaria no teu caso**

Crie a classe que receberá os dados de cada objeto do teu `JSON`

```
class Dados {
    String name;
    String id;

    Conta({
      this.name,
      this.id
    });

    factory Dados.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Dados(
        name: json["name"],
        id: json["id"]
    );
}
```

Para pegar os dados do seu `JSON` faça o seguinte

```
class Items{
  String json = '{"data":[{ "id":1, "name":"Acre" }, { "id":2, "name":"Alagoas" }]}';
  List<Dados> dados;

  void PegarDados(){
    final jsonMap = jsonDecode(json);
    dados = (jsonMap["data"] as List).map((item) => Dados.fromJson(item)).toList();  
  }

  void ClasseMontarItens(){
    PegarDados();
    var primeiroDadoId = dados[0].id;
    var primeiroDadoNome = dados[0].name;

    print("Esse é o primeiro item: $primeiroDadoId - $primeiroDadoNome");
  }
}
```

Comment: Olá Matheus, 
testei seu código,
e ocorre este erro;

Only static members can be accessed in initializers.dart(implicit_this_reference_in_initializer)

final jsonMap = jsonDecode(json);

Comment: Provavelmente você está tentando criar essa variável `final jsonMap = jsonDecode(json);` diretamente na sua classe, tente colocar ela dentro de um método ou apenas declare ela como `var jsonMap;` e depois onde você recebe o valor do `JSON` faça `jsonMap = jsonDecode(json);`

Comment: @Luiz melhorei o meu exemplo, veja se agora fica mais claro!