# Deserializar JSON - Dart/Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

Tenho um JSON e quero joga-lo em um array.

```
final String jsonSample='[{"id":1},{"id":2}]';
var json = jsonDecode(jsonSample);
print (json); //resultado é:  [{id: 1}, {id: 2}]
```

Até ai tudo certo, porém agora queria pegar somente o ID e joga-lo em um array. Como posso fazer?

Answer (score 2):

Aqui nesta pergunta do Stackoverflow eu já respondi algo que resolve sua dúvida [Como comparar valor do Map e Json em flutter?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/421475/87785).

Vi que você conseguiu resolver seu problema, mas segue uma outra maneira, você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

Crie a classe que receberá os dados de cada objeto do teu `JSON`

```
class Conta {
    String nome;
    String email;

    Conta({
      this.nome,
      this.email
    });

    factory Conta.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Conta(
        nome: json["nome"],
        email: json["email"]
    );
}
```

Agora transforme o seu `JSON` em uma Lista que receberá objetos do tipo `Conta`

```
  String json = '[{"nome":"Marcelo", "email":"marcelo@vpeventos.com"}, {"nome":"Caio", "email":"caio@doido.com"}, {"nome":"Caio", "email":"caioloco@eventos.com"}]';
  final jsonMap = jsonDecode(json);

  List<Conta> contas;

  contas = (jsonMap as List).map((item) => Conta.fromJson(item)).toList();
```

Com isso você terá uma lista com todas as contas existentes em seu `JSON`.